# How to obtain R^2 for robust mixed effect model (rlmer command; robustlmm)?

Tags: r, mixed-models, robust

I estimated a robust mixed effect model with the `rlmer`command from the `robustlmm`package. Is there a way to obtain the marginal and conditional R^2 values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just going to answer that myself. I could not find a package or rather a function in R that is equivalent to e.g. `r.squaredGLMM` in the case of `lmerMod` objects but I found a quick workaround that works with `rlmerMod` objects.   Basically you just have to extract the variance components for the fixed effects, random effects and residuals and then manually calcualte the marginal and conditional R^2 based on the formula provided by Nakagawa & Schielzeth (2013).

```
library(robustlmm)
library(insight)
library(lme4)
data(Dyestuff, package = "lme4")
robust.model <- rlmer(Yield ~ 1|Batch, data=Dyestuff)
var.fix <- get_variance_fixed(robust.model)
var.ran <- get_variance_random(robust.model)
var.res <- get_variance_residual(robust.model)
R2m = var.fix/(var.fix+var.ran+var.res)
R2c = (var.fix+var.ran)/(var.fix+var.ran+var.res)
```

Literature:
Nakagawa, S. and Schielzeth, H. (2013), A general and simple method for obtaining R2 from generalized linear mixed‐effects models. Methods Ecol Evol, 4: 133-142. doi:10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x